# How to animate sub-elements inside a carousel Bootstrap.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, callback, carousel

Using the callback "slid" in twitter bootstrap.js, I'm trying to animate pieces individually after transitioning from slide to slide:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="animatefirst.png">
        <h1> second </h1>
        <p> third <p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="animatefirst.png">
        <h1> second </h1>
        <p> third <p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="animatefirst.png">
        <h1> second </h1>
        <p> third <p>
    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see, I'd like to animate the following in order:

1. img
2. h1
3. p

How would I do this?

So far this is all I can do:

```
$('#carousel2').bind('slid', function(){
    $('img').fadeIn();
});
```

But the problem with the above is that it fades in all images at once once the first slide, gets 'slid' in. Is there a way for me to target the image within the div and fade them in one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone out there, I found the solution:

Bootstrap attaches a class called "active" to the current item in the carousel.

I just used a descendent selector to target all of the child elements I needed to animate, and voila, animation!